# Javascript object decrementing with the IF statement

Tags: javascript, object, hash, hashmap

[image]

Hello, I was expecting obj = {a:-2} but am getting obj = {a:0}. It looks like it's not entering the if statements even though the key exists obj[string[0].

How should I best write this? What's the best way to check if the object has an index without using a for in loop since that will take additional O(n) time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

here obj.a = 0 and 0 is a falsy value in javascript. That's why its not hitting the if loop.

To check if a key exist in a object, you can use the below the two methods which return boolean value.

1. obj.hasOwnProperty(key)
2. key in obj

   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(x[0])){
   obj[x[0]]--
   }

Answer (score 0):

The following shows why the if statements are not being hit:

```js
> obj[string[0]];
0
> obj[string[0]] == true
false
> obj[string[0]] == 0;
true
> 0 == true
false
> 0 == false
true
```

You could change the if statements to `obj[string[0]] == 0` to make the code inside the if statements evaluate. Also refer to:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Which tells us that 0 is falsy.